# integral calculator in R

Tags: r, calculator, integral

I know how to use integral calculator to obtain numeric values, but don't know how to get an algebraic equation.

For example:

```
integrand <- function(x) {1/((x+1)*sqrt(x))}
integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
```

with this code, I can get 3.141593 with absolute error `< 2.7e-05`

However, what if I want to use this code:

```
integrand <- function(x) {2*x}
integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)
```

to get `x^2`.

Apparently, it does not work.

If someone can help this, I would appreciate your help. Tons of thanks!

Comment: R doesn't do symbolic math but there are R packages that do. See package [Ryacas](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Ryacas) or [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-as-a-computer-algebra-system-with-ryacas/). See also  package [rSymPy](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rSymPy) or [here](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/symbolic/)

Comment: Actually, you _can_ do some limited symbolic calculations in R with the `Ryacas` package. See [RBloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-as-a-computer-algebra-system-with-ryacas/)

Answer (score 3):

R doesn't do symbolic math but there are R packages that do. I will give (very) short examples using CRAN packages [Ryacas](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Ryacas) and [rSympy](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rSymPy).

**1. Package `Ryacas`.**

```
library(Ryacas)

f <- ysym("2*x")
integrate(f, "x")
#y: x^2
```

**2. Package `rSymPy`.**

With package `rSymPy` you need to define the symbol `"x"` first. This is done with function `Var`.
Note: in my tests, the first time any of `Var` or `sympy` were called a series of warnings were given. I have interrupted R and at the second time all went well.

```
library(rSymPy)

x <- Var("x")
sympy("integrate(2*x)")
#[1] "x**2"
```

Comment: Thank you, Rui! I tried 2*x, it works. But still don't know how to calculate more complicated equations. For example: library(Ryacas) f <- ysym("exp(-x/θ) ") integrate(f, "x")   with this code, it only returns me "y: Integrate(x)exp(-x/θ)".